# Stack Exchange API is returning non-existant/incorrect notices for questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

When you view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) question you do not see any notices other than the protected notice at bottom. Also, you are able to edit the answers and question *(provided you have the privilege)*.

However, when you access the details for the question through the API you get something like this:

```
[93] => stdClass Object
    (
        [question_id] => 3737139
        [last_edit_date] => 1372180382
        [creation_date] => 1284740647
        [score] => 785
        [community_owned_date] => 1284740647
        [protected_date] => 1368947827
        [title] => Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?
        [link] => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php
        [is_answered] => 1
        [close_vote_count] => 0
        [reopen_vote_count] => 0
        [delete_vote_count] => 0
        [notice] => stdClass Object
            (
                [body] => This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: FAQ.
            )
    )
```

It says the question has this notice:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: FAQ.

Which it does not. From what I recall seeing in the past the notice was displayed on the post like on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) question. Even if it is failing to display the notice it's still wrong as I can still modify the posts and moderate it.

Comment: Actually, the question *did* have a notice, which [you can see in the edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3737139/revisions#reveb590cbe-2efa-41e7-9f1d-f227ae4d89df).  It would be nice if the notices showed a "removed" date, as applicable, but I thinks it's good that the API returns the last notice (or all notices), whether it is still in effect or not. The only alternative is to dredge through the `/revisions` paths and that's a major PITA.

Comment: Well that sucks, kinda ruins what I was wanting the info for. =o( Yeah, a removal date or status field would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug here is that deleted notices were still being returned.

This was fixed in the last deploy.